# Enable hermes engine for ios: React native on Mac M1

Tags: ios, react-native, performance, apple-m1, react-native-hermes

After enabling hermes engine in podfile throws error while building app

`"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "vtable for facebook::react::HermesExecutorFactory"`

Hermes version : 0.9.0

RN : 0.66.1

podfile

```
 platform :ios, '11.0'
 target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
 pod 'react-native-onesignal', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal'
end

target '****' do
# Pods for ****
config = use_native_modules!
use_react_native!(path: config['reactNativePath'])

use_react_native!(
:path => config[:reactNativePath],
# to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
:hermes_enabled => true
```

)

Error
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you using reanimated? I had the same issue, and updating reanimated 3.0.0-rc.5 fixed it for me.

Also, a patch has been released for hermes-engine (0.7.2) [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1836#issuecomment-803378838)

You can check this for more info: [thread](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3768#issuecomment-1314969625)

Comment: updating the "reanimated" package works!. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try applying this patch? Seems like some header inclusions are missing.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/88b7b640a74bafd918b8b1cd5d58e1f5ddfb730a